# Centering CAShapeLayer within UIView Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, cashapelayer

I'm having trouble centering CAShapeLayer within a UIView. I've search and most solutions are from pre 2015 in Obj C or haven't been solved.

Attached is what the image looks like. When I inspect it, its inside the  red view, but idk why its not centering. I've tried resizing it but still doesn't work.

[image]

```
let progressView: UIView = {
    let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = .red
    return view
}()

//MARK: - ViewDidLoad
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.addSubview(progressView)
progressView.anchor(top: nil, left: nil, bottom: nil, right: nil, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 200, height: 200)
    progressView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    progressView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

    setupCircleLayers()
}

var shapeLayer: CAShapeLayer!

private func setupCircleLayers() {
    let trackLayer = createCircleShapeLayer(strokeColor: UIColor.rgb(red: 56, green: 25, blue: 49, alpha: 1), fillColor: #colorLiteral(red: 0.9686274529, green: 0.78039217, blue: 0.3450980484, alpha: 1))
    progressView.layer.addSublayer(trackLayer)
}

    private func createCircleShapeLayer(strokeColor: UIColor, fillColor: UIColor) -> CAShapeLayer {

    let centerpoint = CGPoint(x: progressView.frame.width / 2, y: progressView.frame.height / 2)
    let circularPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: centerpoint, radius: 100, startAngle: 0, endAngle: 2 * CGFloat.pi, clockwise: true)
    let layer = CAShapeLayer()
    layer.path = circularPath.cgPath
    layer.fillColor = fillColor.cgColor
    layer.lineCap = kCALineCapRound
    layer.position = progressView.center
    return layer
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As @ukim says, your problem is that you are trying to determine the position of your layer, based on views and their size before these are finite.

When you are in `viewDidLoad` you don't know the size and final position of your views yet. You can add the `progressView` alright but you can not be sure that its size or position are correct until `viewDidLayoutSubviews` (documented [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621398-viewDidlayoutsubviews)).

So, if I move your call to `setupCircleLayers` to `viewDidLayoutSubviews` and I change the centerpoint to `CGPoint.zero` and alter the calculation of your `layer.position` to this:

```
layer.position = CGPoint(x: progressView.frame.size.width / 2, y: progressView.frame.size.height / 2)
```

Then I see this:

[image]

Which I hope is more what you were aiming for.

Here is the complete listing (note that I had to change some of your methods as I didn't have access to `anchor` or `UIColor.rgb` for instance but you can probably work your way around that :))

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var shapeLayer: CAShapeLayer!
    let progressView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .red
        return view
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.addSubview(progressView)
        progressView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        progressView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
        progressView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
        progressView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        progressView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        if shouldAddSublayer {
            setupCircleLayers()
        }
    }

    private func setupCircleLayers() {
        let trackLayer = createCircleShapeLayer(strokeColor: UIColor.init(red: 56/255, green: 25/255, blue: 49/255, alpha: 1), fillColor: #colorLiteral(red: 0.9686274529, green: 0.78039217, blue: 0.3450980484, alpha: 1))
        progressView.layer.addSublayer(trackLayer)
    }

    private var shouldAddSublayer: Bool {
        /*
         check if:
         1. we have any sublayers at all, if we don't then its safe to add a new, so return true
         2. if there are sublayers, see if "our" layer is there, if it is not, return true 
        */
        guard let sublayers = progressView.layer.sublayers else { return true }
        return sublayers.filter({ $0.name == "myLayer"}).count == 0
    }

    private func createCircleShapeLayer(strokeColor: UIColor, fillColor: UIColor) -> CAShapeLayer {
        let centerpoint = CGPoint.zero
        let circularPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: centerpoint, radius: 100, startAngle: 0, endAngle: 2 * CGFloat.pi, clockwise: true)
        let layer = CAShapeLayer()
        layer.path = circularPath.cgPath
        layer.fillColor = fillColor.cgColor
        layer.lineCap = kCALineCapRound
        layer.position = CGPoint(x: progressView.frame.size.width / 2, y: progressView.frame.size.height / 2)
        layer.name = "myLayer"
        return layer
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.

### Caveat

When you do the above, that also means that *every time* `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is called, you are adding a new layer. To circumvent that, you can use the `name` property of a layer

```
layer.name = "myLayer"
```

and then check if you have already added your layer. Something like this should work:

```
private var shouldAddSublayer: Bool {
    /*
     check if:
     1. we have any sublayers at all, if we don't then its safe to add a new, so return true
     2. if there are sublayers, see if "our" layer is there, if it is not, return true

    */
    guard let sublayers = progressView.layer.sublayers else { return true }
    return sublayers.filter({ $0.name == "myLayer"}).count == 0
}
```

Which you then use here:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    if shouldAddSublayer {
        setupCircleLayers()
    }
}
```

I've updated the listing.

Comment: Note : you have to wrap the code inside **viewDidLayoutSubviews** in a bool flag as it's called multiple times

Comment: @Sh_Khan yeah I just thought of that as well, nice catch :) Updated my answer

Comment: Glad it worked, sorry you cried :). Please see my update, as @Sh_Khan writes, you need to check if the layer has already been added before attempting to add it.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `setupCircleLayers()`in `viewDidLoad()`. At the time, `progressView.frame` has not been calculated from the constraints yet.

Try

```
let centerpoint = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100)
```

instead of calculating the value from `progressView.frame`

You can try this in your playground:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport


class MyVC: UIViewController {
    let progressView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .red
        return view
    }()

    var layer: CAShapeLayer?


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.addSubview(progressView)
        progressView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        progressView.backgroundColor = .red
        progressView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
        progressView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
        progressView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        progressView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

        setupCircleLayers()
    }

    var shapeLayer: CAShapeLayer!

    private func setupCircleLayers() {
        let trackLayer = createCircleShapeLayer(strokeColor: .red, fillColor: #colorLiteral(red: 0.9686274529, green: 0.78039217, blue: 0.3450980484, alpha: 1))
        progressView.layer.addSublayer(trackLayer)
    }

    private func createCircleShapeLayer(strokeColor: UIColor, fillColor: UIColor) -> CAShapeLayer {

        let centerpoint = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100)
        let circularPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: centerpoint, radius: 100, startAngle: 0, endAngle: 2 * CGFloat.pi, clockwise: true)
        let layer = CAShapeLayer()
        layer.path = circularPath.cgPath
        layer.fillColor = fillColor.cgColor
        layer.lineCap = kCALineCapRound
        return layer
    }
}

let containerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 375.0, height: 667.0))
let vc = MyVC()
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = vc.view
```

Comment: That still didn't work. I've been stuck on this problem for the past few days! Don't know what's wrong

Comment: @KennyHo I edited the answer. You can put the code in playground.

Comment: @KennyHo  You need to comment this line **layer.position = progressView.center** for this answer to work

Comment: Thank you @Sh_Khan. Your help and review was much appreciated!