# Center a bezier path to a UIview?

Tags: swift, animation, uikit, constraints, uibezierpath

For the life of me, I cannot center this bezier path (the circle displayed below).  The orange view is properly constrained and horizontally aligned, however when I add 3 layers to the orange view using the method below, I cannot seem to center it to the orange view.  I declared the orange view as `spinnerHolder`.

[image]

```
private func createCircleShapeLayer(strokeColor: UIColor, fillColor: UIColor) -> CAShapeLayer {
    let layer = CAShapeLayer()

    //The farther from 0 x is for this, the more separated the movements of the 3 paths.
    let circularPath = UIBezierPath(
        arcCenter: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0),
        radius: 30,
        startAngle: 0,
        endAngle: 2 * CGFloat.pi,
        clockwise: true
    )
    layer.path = circularPath.cgPath
    layer.strokeColor = strokeColor.cgColor
    layer.lineWidth = 3
    layer.fillColor = fillColor.cgColor
    layer.lineCap = kCALineCapRound
    layer.position = spinnerHolder.center
    return layer
}
```

Answer (score 4):

1- Change `arcCenter` to

```
let circularPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x:spinnerHolder.frame.width/2, y:spinnerHolder.frame.height/2),
                                radius: 30,
                                startAngle: 0,
                                endAngle: 2 * CGFloat.pi,
                                clockwise: true)
```

2- Comment this

```
layer.position = spinnerHolder.center
```

3- Call the method inside `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

```
var once = false
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    if once {
        spinnerHolder.addSublayer(createCircleShapeLayer(,,,,,))
        once = false
    }
}
```

calling inside `viewDidLayoutSubviews` isn't mandatory  , add it anytime/anywhere but not before the VC loads

4- Check this [Centering CAShapeLayer within UIView Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51847041/centering-cashapelayer-within-uiview-swift/51847255#51847255)

Answer (score 2):

set arcCenter point as

```
let centerPoint = CGPoint(x:self.viewRect.bounds.midX, y: self.viewRect.bounds.midY)
```